# Windows Azure Mobile and notification hub services

Tags: windows, azure, mobile, notifications

I want to ask that if I sign up for windows azure mobile and notification hub services, is it going to work for my mobile apps? because my country is Bahrain located in Middle East Arab

Comment: Please read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Your country is listed in the countries/regions where Azure is commercially available.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/faq/